# How to convert Image to PDF in Android

Tags: android

Apart from using iTextPDF library to convert image file to a PDF file, is there any way to do it without using library or using an open source library.

Comment: itextpdf is also open source

Comment: But this link does not suggest the same.

Comment: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/can-i-use-itext-without-respecting-agpl-license

Comment: then use [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/)

Comment: I think it only supports converting Text to PDF and not image to PDF

Comment: Take a look it has all features. (it's not converting it is inserting image inside PDF)

Comment: Ya thanks it worked

Comment: How to accept your comment as solution

Comment: i added my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) it is a open source lib

**use this to insert image in pdf**

```
    PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(someImage);
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
float width = bimg.getWidth();
float height = bimg.getHeight();
PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
document.addPage(page); 
PDXObjectImage img = new PDJpeg(document, new FileInputStream(someImage));
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
contentStream.close();
in.close();

document.save("test.pdf");
document.close();
```